# How can I open the 2011 MacBook Air without damaging the screws?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I would like to open the MBA, I don't have the screwdriver that fits:

[image: MBA screw]

Is there a way to remove the screws without the 5 points pentalobe required?

The ideal solution would be to do this without damaging the screws.

Comment: Anything but the correct tool will damage the screws.  You can form your own tool with a file and an old screwdriver, but it will damage the screws unless you are incredibly precise.  You can use a plastic like ShapeLock to form your own screw driver tip, but it probably won't have enough force to unscrew or screw them successfully.  You could use superglue to attach a smaller hex wrench to the screw, then nail polish remover to detach it.  But all of these methods will very likely damage the screw or the macbook. You can get the correct tool from inexpensively and quickly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot safely remove it without the proper tool and the correct touch. You want to place the driver on the tangent to the case (the screws enter at an angle - not vertical compared to the keyboard plane.

iFixit.com and other places sell the pentalobe tool for less than $15 and it's money well spent to avoid needing to get Apple to replace the screws should you strip them.

Comment: A giant plus one to this answer. This isn't one of those times when *vise grips* is the correct answer—use the proper tool, or take the unit to someone who will.

Comment: Well, indeed I hoped for a magic trick I guess. If as I suspect Apple will use these on the next MacBooks, I will definitely buy one of these screw drivers then.

Comment: It's a great question and will be very helpful for others, and it's a very natural thought. _"If I could just get enough purchase from tool X"_

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this with a 1.2mm flathead, it obviously doesn't have as much torque as a pentalobe driver, but it doesn't strip the heads if you're careful.

Also, this trick works, but you need the right pen (hard clear bic):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONd7quApjGM